# How can one protect against while(true) loops in javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have been working with teaching kids programming in Javascript using a combination of online and self made environment.

At some stage most of the kids encounter a time when they create an infinite loop.  In days gone by. an infinite loop was expected to be a child's first program with

```
10 PRINT "Mike is cool"
20 GOTO 10
```

Writing something like that in JavaScript is problematic

```
while(true) {
   print("Mike is cool");
}
```

Doesn't work because of the synchronous nature of JavaScript, and that's something that they will have to learn.  The problem isn't that their program doesn't work as expected, but when they run their program *the entire world stops!*

Some Browsers have enough control remaining to close the window,  some just Lock.  If you are using an in-browser environment (like jsfiddle, jsbin etc) you don't have enough control to stop the rogue "task"

You can't audit the code beforehand (It literally *is* the halting problem), but is there any reasonable way of mitigating the symptoms?

The programming environment on Khan Academy seems to achieve this

http://www.khanacademy.org/cs/breaking/4804951998988288

What is it doing to handle the excessive run-time?  How is it managing to do this while the while is still running?

Comment: You could run it through `setInterval()`

Comment: I believe Khan Academy and Codecademy and such sites run their code on a server, and not locally, where they have much more control and monitoring abilities and do not run the code in the user's browser.

Comment: Perhaps you can cover the basics (which would include that case) using a command line JavaScript interpreter (e.g., V8 in Node.js). Let them make a script in Notepad (or a proper editor) and just run it with `node script.js`. If they create an infinite loop, CTRL-C out of it. Not as flashy as those online tools, but not a bad place to start.

Comment: There are also web workers, but they are likely to create more problems than they are going to solve.

Comment: What "*doesn't work because of the synchronous nature of JavaScript*"?

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this in a browser by using a web worker, which does not lock the UI thread of the web browser because the browser runs a separate thread for the web worker. Your looping code for the example would be run in the web worker.

Web worker threads are an HTML5 feature so this approach will not work on older browsers. You can set breakpoints and debug web workers, at least in Chrome and Safari. You can learn the basics of web worker threads at:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/